# Need help in deciding correct punctuation.

Tags: punctuation

So, I just wrote down the following sentence.

'Now my attempt is to understand the cause of such behaviour. Is it the childhood experiences, as we find in the movie?'

I'm not sure if I've got the punctuation correct in the last sentence with the use of question mark. If reading out, you'd expect the speaker to take a pause after 'experiences' and then provide more information. However, 'as we find in the movie' isn't really an interrogative so putting the question market after it seems erroneous. Kindly suggest the correct punctuation.

Comment: 'Is it the childhood experiences, as the movie implies?' makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is correct.

The comma after 'experiences' warns readers the nature of the sentence may be changing into something else. You end up with the interrogative, comma, then a parenthetic aside (an extra detail not essential to the sentence).

You still need to end this sentence with a question mark.

The principle for parenthetic asides is the sentence must be correct if you delete them plus the comma(s) used to separate them from the main body of the sentence.

Comment: Don't forget to come back later. Someone with more experience may add to or correct my answer. I'm confident, but not certain, it's all you need to know.

Comment: I shall gladly retract the upvote if your answer is proved wrong. :)